# Are there lifecycle hooks in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am new to ASP.NET MVC, but have experience with other MVC frameworks - mostly CakePHP. Is there anything resembling a lifecycle event system in ASP.NET MVC? I'd like to be able to plug into framework lifecycle and perform some logic - for example do global request logging by registering a listener in a controller initialization event.

I know this can be achieved in a numerous ways - this is a general question about ASP.NET lifecycle events functionality, not about implementing request logging in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Yes, this sort of thing is covered by the official MVC tutorials.  You can also google the MVC request pipeline.

Comment: What 'sort of thing'? I have seached for "ASP.NET MVC lifecycle event system" and got information about the lifecycle but not the event system.

Comment: There is no event system in MVC.  Follow the tutorials if you want to know how to plug into the request pipeline.

Comment: Would you be so kind and provide a link to tutorial that shows how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application).

[image: MVC5 life cycle]

Depending on what you want to do you have to hook into different places.